# Get correct counts from grouped by values from a XREF Table that depend on values from other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get correct counts from grouped by values from a XREF Table that depend on values from other tables?

I have tables of
Person
Event
XPersonEvent

```
Person
----------------------------------
PersonID  FirstName    DateCanceled
----------------------------------
10        Joe          null
20        Bob          01/01/2024
30        Lou          null

Event
----------------------------------
EventID   EventName    MaxAttendees
----------------------------------
100       Austin       55
200       Boston       65
300       Cleveland    75

XPersonEvent
----------------------------------
ID        PersonID     EventID
----------------------------------
1000       10          100
1001       20          100
1002       30          100
1003       30          300
```

---

### This SQL gives me the following report.

```
Select
e.EventName, e.MaxAttendees,
count(xpe.EventID) as #Registered,
count(xpe.EventID) as #Attending From [Event] as e

Join XPersonEvent as xpe on xpe.EventID = e.EventID
Join Person as p on p.PersonID = xpe.PersonID

where p.DateCanceled is null 
Group By e.EventName, e.MaxAttendees
Order by e.EventName

EventName     MaxAttendees #Registered #Attending
------------- ------------ ----------- -----------
Austin        55           2           2
Cleveland     75           1           1
```

---

### What needs to be changed is

1. I need to see all events even if they do not have anyone registered
   (and #Registered = 0 #Attending = 0 for them)
2. I need correct counts of both
   #Registered (DateCanceld null and not null)
   #Attending  (DateCanceld is null )

How do I get this report?

```
EventName     MaxAttendees #Registered #Attending
------------- ------------ ----------- -----------
Austin        55           3           2
Boston        65           0           0
Cleveland     75           1           1
```

Comment: Your `Date Cancelled` field is in a wrong table. Move it to `XPersonEvent`.  To have all events you need to switch to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: left joins fixes problem#1 but I can't move DateCanceled because this is a 20 year old DB with lots of code and stuff in place and also DateCanceld logicially applies to a person (because of the way this db was set up non standard there is a unique person record for each Event)

Comment: @Austin Switch it to a left join like you've said. Then count(XPersonEvent.PersonID) as num_registered. And either change the inner join to Person to a left join with p.DateCanceled is null in the join condition rather than WHERE. Then count(person.PersonID) will give you num_attending. Or you can keep the join to person INNER remove the cancelledDate filter, and do sum(1) as num_registered, sum(case when DateCancelled is null then 1 else 0 end) as num_attending.

Comment: Use `conditional aggregation` for "#Attending": `SUM(CASE DateCanelled IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include rows that do not have a match
2. `COUNT()` in SQL Server excludes null values, which is helpful for `OUTER JOIN` but it counts all rows, if you want different counts from the same record set for different criteria you can use `COUNT(CASE )` to only include values/rows that you want to be counted.

> I need to see all events even if they do not have anyone registered

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN XPersonEvent as xpe on xpe.EventID = e.EventID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person as p on p.PersonID = xpe.PersonID
```

This will mean that all the rows in the `FROM` table will be returned, even if there is no matching row in `XPersonEvent` or `Person`. For all the events with no match, the values from the joined tables will be `NULL`.

This doesn't have a direct impact on `COUNT()` because the null values are excluded.

> I need correct counts of both #Registered (DateCanceld null and not null) #Attending (DateCanceld is null)

This is less intuitive but when you need to count multiple *different criteria* in the same result set, you can't define that criteria in the `WHERE` clause, especially if you want all of the *LEFT* rows (in the FROM table) to be returned.

#### #Registered

This count needs to include all `XPersonEvent` records, even if they have been cancelled. So removing the `WHERE` criteria will fix this.

#### #Attending

This count needs to include only the rows that have not been cancelled, so rows where the expression `p.DateCanceled is null` is true. So we use that in a `CASE` statement:

```
COUNT(CASE 
    WHEN p.DateCanceled is null 
    AND xpe.EventID IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1 END) AS #Attending
```

> It is important to also add criteria to match only when the `XPersonEvent` record exists, remember that the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will leave all other columns `NULL` so we do not want these included in the count if there are *no* registrations at all.

Here I have used an arbitrary value `1` to count the row, the column in this case is not relevant and `1` is a conventional way to represent this. There is no ELSE clause in the above CASE statement which means that any rows that do not match will have a value of `NULL`, which means they will not be counted, exactly what we want here.

We can put this all together:

```
Select
e.EventName, e.MaxAttendees,
count(xpe.EventID) as #Registered,
COUNT(CASE 
    WHEN p.DateCanceled is null 
         AND xpe.EventID IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1 END) AS #Attending
From [Event] as e

LEFT OUTER Join XPersonEvent as xpe on xpe.EventID = e.EventID
LEFT OUTER Join Person as p on p.PersonID = xpe.PersonID

Group By e.EventName, e.MaxAttendees
Order by e.EventName
```

**NOTE:** In some other RDBMS this *trick* with `COUNT(CASE )` doesn't work if they do *count* nulls, instead you have to use `SUM(CASE ... THEN 1 ELSE 0)`

| EventName | MaxAttendees | #Registered | #Attending |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Austin | 55 | 3 | 2 |
| Boston | 65 | 0 | 0 |
| Cleveland | 75 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Your sql as shown "almost" works. Everything is correct except I get a 1 for #Attending for Boston (Boston doesn't have any xref records thus should be 0 for attending.) Boston Is showing 0 for #Registered tho.

Comment: Glad you were able to sort it out!